# Generate random boolean attribute TypeScript

Tags: typescript, random, boolean

How can one assign to a an object which has a *boolean* property **random** **values** of true or false?

```
items: any[];

items.forEach( (item) => {
   item.randomBooleanProperty = ...; //true of false
});
```

Comment: Not sure i follow, are you trying to generate a random boolean value?

Comment: exactly, sorry for lack of coherence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this example:
In this code, we check whether the random number which is between 0 and 1 is greater than 0.5, so we have a 50% to get true and 50% to get false.

```
items: any[];

items.forEach( (item) => {
   item.randomBooleanProperty = Math.random() >= 0.5; //true of false
});
```

Comment: *"...between 0 and 1..."* Specifically (and this is important in terms of getting a correct result from your code, which **is** correct), the value will be `0 <= n < 1`, so `0.5` is the precise midpoint. (I tend to use `< 0.5`, but `>= 0.5` works just as well.)

Comment: You can even bias the result by editing the `0.5` value like if you want it to be true 70% of the time just put `0.3`.